# Drop rows that exist in other dataframe, using 2 different columns

Tags: python, pandas

i got the following problem: Got 2 pandas dataframes, like :

```
importdf:
     System   Email
 1   Basic    testimail@yahoo.com
 2   Basic    anotheremail@yahoo.com
 3   Backend  newemail@yahoo.com

userdf:
     System   Email
 1   Basic    testimail@yahoo.com
 2   Backend   anotheremail@yahoo.com
 3   Basic    newemail@yahoo.com
```

What i need to do, is to drop every row in importdf, that exist in userdf. Because i got some extra columns with different data in the original DataFrames, i can't just tell pandas to remove dublicated rows. At this point, im using the following code to deal with that:

```
importdf_system = importdf['System'].tolist()
importdf_emails = importdf['Email'].tolist()

userdf_system = userdf['System'].tolist()
userdf_emails = userdf['Email'].tolist()

importdf.reset_index(drop=True)
userdf.reset_index(drop=True)

counter = len(importdf)
for i in range(len(importdf)):
    counter = counter - 1
    print(counter)
    for j in range(len(userdf)):
        if "@" in str(importdf_emails[i]) and "@" in str(userdf_emails[j]) and str(importdf_emails[i]).lower() == str(userdf_emails[j]).lower():
            importdf = importdf.drop([i])
```

Sometimes, that code works well, but needs hours to run, because the dataframes are huge. Also, sometimes, i am getting errors like `KeyError: '[1782] not found in axis'`

I've looked to find better way, but didn't find useful sollution. Found a way to use 1 column to look for existing data, but the problem is, that i need to remove the rows, only if the system and the emails are same. for example, if i got same email but with different system on the row, it have to stay.

Comment: Exactly. If  system and email are same, i need to drop the row. if system is different but the email is same, i need it to stay.

Comment: You could try to solve this with numpy.where(). https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do an left merge and specify values that are only in the left data frame.

```
new_df = (
    pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["System", "Email"], how="left", indicator=True)
    .query('_merge == "left_only"')
    .drop("_merge", 1)
)


print(new_df)

    System                   Email
1    Basic  anotheremail@yahoo.com
2  Backend      newemail@yahoo.com
```

### Details

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['System','Email'],how='left',indicator=True)

    System                   Email     _merge
0    Basic     testimail@yahoo.com       both # < we will drop this.
1    Basic  anotheremail@yahoo.com  left_only
2  Backend      newemail@yahoo.com  left_only
```

Comment: @Scotty1- thanks my man :) it's a simple solution using SQL all day :)

Comment: Yeah, I should be unsing SQL statements to a larger extent...

Comment: @Datanovice , is there any way to do pd.merge, case INsensitive ? i forgot to say that emails can be different like : Alexru@yahoo.com and AlexRU@yahoo.com

Comment: @InsaneProperties you will need to use `str.lower()` on both columns before merging I believe.

Comment: @Datanovice i already used `str.lower()` , to see if there is any difference. It works well, but the final results is lowered (like alex@yahoo.com), while i need them in original state (AlexRU@yahoo.com) . Im asking if i can do `str.lower()` just while merging the dataframes, not to do it stay permanently on the results. If you look at my code, you will say that i use str.lower just for the if statement, not applying it anywhere.

Comment: if your dataframe is small, lets say < 1M Records, you can a new column in your left df that is your `email_original`, then merge on Email while it is lowered and remove the extra columns. @InsaneProperties

Answer (score 0):

To keep with new row

```
#Check column which is a concat of System and Email


 userdf['check']=userdf.System.str.cat(userdf.Email)
 importdf['check']=importdf.System.str.cat(importdf.Email)
```

#`Use np.where to check and attribu`te

```
 res=userdf.assign(filter=np.where([x not in y for x, y in zip(userdf.check,importdf.check)],'drop','keep')).drop(columns=['check'])
print(res)

      System                Email    filter
1    Basic     testimail@yahoo.com   keep
2  Backend  anotheremail@yahoo.com   drop
3    Basic      newemail@yahoo.com   drop
```